# Creating a superclass that incorporates a HyperLinkistener and a MouseAdapter

Tags: java, superclass

I have one class called HyperlinkEventMonitor that implements a HyperlinkListener.    I want to extend this class so that it handles both hyperlink events and mouseevents.   I tried creating a superclass but I'm not doing this right because I can't compile the code.   Can someone show me how to do this.

For example:   I tried

```
class    MouseHyperLink extends HyperlinkEventMonitor, implements MouseListener {
```

}

But this is wrong.

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: Is it just the ","? Try: class    MouseHyperLink extends HyperlinkEventMonitor implements MouseListener {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further information on the error message I'll guess that it is the comma-character that messes things up. Try removing the comma-character:

```
class MouseHyperLink extends HyperlinkEventMonitor implements MouseListener {
    // ...
}
```

Also, make sure that you implement all methods of `MouseListener`.

---

If you **don't want to implement all methods in `MouseListener`** (and defer that to the subclass) you'll have to make the class abstract:

```
abstract class MouseHyperLink extends HyperlinkEventMonitor
                              implements MouseListener {
}
```